# File write are serialized in PHP

Tags: php, xampp, mamp

I have a script where I create a new file and build up a .CSV file

```
$name = $_POST['file_name'];
$file = fopen('path/to/file_'.$name.'.csv','w');
$line = '"first_value","second_value"'...;
fwrite($file, $line."\n");
```

This script is embedded in a MAMP Server Web Site so it could be possible that a user opens a first tab in a Browser and call this script and then a second tab in the same browser and launch the same script in parallel. What I would expect is that, since the two file are different, the file write should be done in parallel, but it happens the opposite:

It waits for the first write finish and then start creating the second file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: PHP is single threaded! Also there is more proper way to create CVS file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: @Justinas - though each separate request should be running in its own thread

Comment: How exactly do you validate your hypothesis?

Comment: @DanFromGermany CSV files I am creating takes some seconds to complete ( like 2.000.000 of rows ), so if there would be a parallel creation the two files should be created (empty at the beginning) and then each one filled; but the second CSV is created (empty) only when the first CSV is completed...

Comment: @Justinas Yes, but I expect that each tab of a browser is a different thread, or if this were false from a tab I could access to a variable from another tab

Comment: Can you try to not only open 2 tabs, but try to open the second call on a different computer or browser? There might be a chance the browser is blocking the second request until there is the first bit of a response in the first call.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, from a different browser, on the same machine it works, it generates in parallel the two CSV... The point is, I saw a creation of a CSV in parallel in the same browser, so It has to be possible (on Chrome to be specific) .-.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I conclude the following.

1. It doesn't make sense PHP is waiting for the first file to be written when the files are not the same. This would be a different case ("File Locks").
2. It does make sense that the browser does actually wait, when you have several tabs to the same resource / domain, that it makes sure to receive at least a single byte of the response until it starts firing the other requests.

When trying things like that, you should either use different computers, or use the console in combination with curl or wget (or a PHP / bash script!) without caching.

Comment: Yes, in fact to avoid this I'm using different browsers, but I should test my application on a big number of concurrent access, and the fact that I could use a browser just as 1 It is a big problem :)

Comment: I don't know cURL and wget but it seems that they can actually download a file from the server, and not create it on the server... Or maybe there is a use known to me?

Comment: @FrankB. "Download" means, "make a request and save the response locally". With those tools you can make a request to the URL which does create the file for you (client to server request). There is no need to save any response.

Comment: But when I run a PHP page on my browser, It runs on the server, or on my machine and then send response to the server?

Comment: PHP doesn't run on the browser, it runs on the server. The browser sends a request and the server responds with a response.

Comment: Ok, now It's clear... So you think that using cURL to create the file, instead of the usual fwrite could fix?
I could try to send the request to create the file in the PHP Page through cURL instead of fwrite, so each client will send the request to the Server, and maybe the bottleneck (that seems to be browser's fault) will be bypassed.

Comment: You don't use curl to create a file, you use PHP to create the file and curl to send the request to the server, where PHP runs on. Just sayin.. browser may block its on consecutive calls, but curl on console usually doesn't. curl is like your browser in that case.

Comment: Oh ok... You mean: Use Console and cURL so send the request, instead of using browser... But I need the browser because my application must have a GUI :( I think I have to give up with this... If using console instead of browser is the only possible way... Thanks

Comment: @FrankB. you can copy ANY browser request and send it via console, you can send cookies, headers and parameters...